# register_post_type()'s rewrite slug not working

Tags: custom-post-types

I'm creating a theme for personal use and in wp-content/mu-plugins/custom-types.php, i set

```
function artwork_post_types()
{
    register_post_type('artwork', array(
        'public' => true,
        'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-art',
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => 'Artwork',
            'add_new_item' => 'Add New Artwork',
            'edit_item' => 'Edit Artwork',
            'all_items' => 'All Artwork',
            'singular_name' => 'Artwork',
            'pages' => true,
            'rewrite' => array(
                'slug' => 'art',
                'with_front' => false,
            ))
    ));
 }

add_action('init', 'artwork_post_types');
```

After that, I went to click on Settings -> Permalinks -> Save Changes to update. However it seems the slug rewriting is not working as i hoped.

The permalink still reflects as 'artwork' instead of 'art'
i.e. http://domain/**artwork**/test instead of http://domain/**art**/test instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is because your `rewrite` [argument](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/#parameters) is part of the `labels`, but `rewrite` is actually same level as the `labels`, so just move the `rewrite` to after the `labels` and the problem will be gone. :)

```php
register_post_type('artwork', array(
    'public'    => true,
    'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-art',
    'labels'    => array(
        'name'          => 'Artwork',
        'add_new_item'  => 'Add New Artwork',
        'edit_item'     => 'Edit Artwork',
        'all_items'     => 'All Artwork',
        'singular_name' => 'Artwork',
    ),
    // Move the "rewrite" to below:
    'rewrite'   => array(
        'slug'       => 'art',
        'with_front' => false,
        'pages'      => true, // this also belongs in "rewrite" and not "labels"
    ),
));
```

Comment: such a careless mistake by me. Thank you for pointing that out!